# SELECT inside of INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This part of code :

```
INSERT INTO koszyk_produkt (ID_koszyk,ID_produkt,Ilosc) 
VALUES (
(SELECT ID FROM koszyk 
WHERE ID_klient=IDk),
IDp,Ilosc);
```

works perfectly fine when tested in HeidiSQL (MariaDB), but fails with two errors when I try to apply this in phpMyAdmin (the same engine):

```
A comma or a closing bracket was expected (near SELECT)
Unexpected token. (near ID)
```

I'm lack of ideas how to make this work.

@EDIT
I forgot to add - this is procedure, and **IDk** **IDp** **Ilosc** are arguments.

Comment: This query doesn't seem to make any sense.  What is `IDk`? Are `IDp` and `Ilosc` supposed to be columns of `koszyk`?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that - this is procedure and IDk, IDp and Ilosc are arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the ID and use the arguments as the 2nd and 3rd columns.

```
INSERT  INTO koszyk_produkt
        (ID_koszyk,ID_produkt,Ilosc)
SELECT  ID,
        IDp,
        Ilosc
FROM    koszyk
WHERE   ID_klient = IDk
```